# Spring Factory to create synchronous consumers listening to the queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms

I am new to Spring Boot and coding for my college project work and I need some help.
I want to create a spring boot application, which starts a factory class that will create and starts 10 synchronous clients. These clients must be listening constantly to the queues. Below is my code. I am not sure, if I am on right track and need some help. Is my implementation correct? How can I make sure that 10 synchronous clients are created? How do I use identifier to identify which  message client processed the message ?

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public MesFactory mesFactory(){
        return new MesFactory();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

public class MesFactory {

    private ExecutorService executorService = 

    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    @PostConstruct
    public void build(){
        executorService.execute(() -> new MesClient());
    }
}


@Component
@EnableJms
public class MesClient {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MesClient.class);

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @JmsListener(destination = "incoming-messages-queue")
    public void receive(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
        doPerformMessage(message);
    }

    public void doPerformMessage(String message){
       // parsing happens here
    } 

    @Bean
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new RMQConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 100000000L)
    public void sendMessage() {

        String message= "Hi World";

        // Coerce a javax.jms.MessageCreator
        MessageCreator messageCreator = (Session session) -> {
            return session.createTextMessage(message);
        };

        // And publish to RabbitMQ using Spring's JmsTemplate
        jmsTemplate.send("incoming-messages-queue", messageCreator);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "synchronous clients". That code will create a single asynchronous consumer.

Comment: I wanted to create 10 message clients listening to the same queue to process a message. Once, the message gets consumed by the message client, then it should synchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the boot properties...

```
spring.jms.listener.concurrency=10
spring.jms.listener.max-concurrency=10
```

The listener container will start 10 threads - each consuming from the same queue; they will invoke the JMS listener method.

See the [Spring Boot documentation - Application Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) and scroll down to the JMS section.

Comment: I set those properties. It looks like if I publish 100 messages, all seems to be getting consumed from 1 client. Is there any way to know which message client picked up a message from the queue to process.

Comment: If you are using ActiveMQ; I think he uses a default prefetch of 1000 which means one consumer will get all 100 messages. You need to configure ActiveMQ to reduce the prefetch to better distribute the messages. [See here](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html). If you write a log message (e.g. via slf4j), boot's default configuration includes the thread name - each consumer runs on a distinct thread.